# Step out of current function with GDB

Tags: gdb

Those who use Visual Studio will be familiar with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> [hotkey](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/10/29/step-out-of-or-over-a-method/), which steps out of a function, meaning it continues execution of the current function until it returns to its caller, at which point it stops.

Is there an equivalent in GDB?

Comment: Similarly, in IDLE-python's debugger, the command is the "out" button.

Answer (score 341, accepted):

You can use the `finish` command.

> `finish`: Continue running until just after function in the selected stack frame returns. Print the returned value (if any). This command can be abbreviated as `fin`.

(See *[5.2 Continuing and Stepping](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Continuing-and-Stepping.html)*.)